# Getting single, specific drive status using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Running this:

```
$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive
ForEach ($Drive in $WMI){
     $Drive.DeviceID + ": " + $Drive.Status
}
```

Returns results like:

```
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1: OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0: OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2: OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3: OK
```

Is there an easy way to restrict results to \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0?

Basically, I am trying to return a simple "OK" for Physical Drive 0's health.

I tried the following:

```
$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive
ForEach ($Drive in $WMI | Where $Drive.DeviceID -Contains "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0"){
 $Drive.Status
}
```

But nothing is outputted (at all). How would I restrict the status output to just the Physical Drive 0 from DeviceID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
$WMI = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive
ForEach ($Drive in $WMI) {
if ($Drive.DeviceID -contains "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0") { 
    $Drive.Status
    }
}
```

You look thru `$wmi` and check if each value contains this specific value.
If you have a match, it will show the Disk status.

Comment: Ah, the solution is so simple. Thank you very much!

Marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, depending on how specific you wish to be:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object DeviceID -eq '\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0'
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object DeviceID -match 'E0$'
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object Index    -eq 0
```

If you wish these to run on older versions of PowerShell, then use the older syntax by placing each "test" into a scriptblock:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq '\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0' }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also very helpful to me!